# Extracting coordinates from histogram created with PyPlot in Julia

Tags: matplotlib, julia

I created a histogram with the following code

```
using PyPlot
devx = randn(10000)
figure("pyplot_histogram")
plt.hist(devx, 10)
grid("on")
    xlabel("deviation in x direction in \$\\mu m\$")
    ylabel("number of deviations")
```

and would like to somehow extract the coordinates generated by that process to a text file to further work with that in GNUPlot. How can I do that?

Comment: I haven't kept up with the latest julia plotting interfaces, but I'm pretty sure `figure` isn't a native julia command. What are you running exactly?

Comment: I am running PyPlot. I edited the post to give more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming* you're using `PyPlot` and your *actual* code looks something like this:

```julia
using PyPlot
devx = randn(10000);
figure("pyplot_histogram");
plt.hist(devx, 10);
grid(true);   # note: grid("on") is deprecated
xlabel("deviation in x direction in \$\\mu m\$");
ylabel("number of deviations");
```

Then, you can replace line 4 with

```julia
MyHist = plt.hist(devx, 10);
```

You can now inspect this object's property names

```julia
propertynames(MyHist)   #> (1,2,3)
```

Inspecting those one by one reveals that

- `MyHist[1]` corresponds to the bin heights
- `MyHist[2]` corresponds to the bin edges
- `MyHist[3]` corresponds to the actual rectangular patch objects drawn

---

<sub>* also assuming that Julia hasn't changed, like 50 versions, since I last used it, which seemed to happen a lot when I was last using it :p</sub>